# Trying to identify a comic about a girl and a robot break into a lab to steal experimental chip

Tags: story-identification, comics, robots, webcomics

I'm on an impossible task to try to identify a comic I read online.  It was a free PDF (maybe 30 pages long?) and was the first part of a story about a girl whose dad (or something similar) brings home a robot from a lab?  I think they go on to break into the lab to try and steal some experiment chip?  Or perhaps he already had the chip installed in him and they snuck the robot home to protect him from something?  I read it maybe four or five years ago and cannot for the life of me remember what it was, except that it was really good!

Any help or pointers would be amazing!

Many thanks,

Shaw.

Comment: This sounds vaguely like the first (or maybe the 12th) chapter of [Gunnerkrigg Court](http://www.gunnerkrigg.com/?p=1)

Comment: I like @KernalPanic's answer, but I'm also wondering whether we can safely rule out [O Human Star](http://ohumanstar.com/). Regardless, both comics are wonderful!

Comment: It also sounds like a ver compressed version of Foundation.